# I am looking for a svn helper program

Tags: svn

I didn't remember the name of this program. But i can remember how it works.

Program is working on tray. When we double click on it it is showing its main window. :)

I could add some criterias to make automatic commit(and maybe update). 
For ex: if a file changes or if files to be deleted, you can commit.

The best part of this program is: "it is FREE"

I don't remember exactly but i think it has M name in its name (but i don't remember).

I think this program written by an Italian man. And its web site was very simple (and i think its fonts were green)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVN Monitor?

http://www.svnmonitor.com/default.shtml

Comment: HEYYOOOO.... thank you so much.. Its name is very easy but i couldn't remember :) I am very happy like children :))))) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Commit Monitor ?

http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor

M.

Comment: this is also good. But this isn't what i am looking for. Thank you. And please let it stay your answer.